# How to close the command window of a batch file which was started by another batch file

Tags: cmd, window

I created a perl script which starts another script. But the started script must be closed after it has performed its task. How can I do it? I have tried the EXIT command but i didnt work.

Answer (score 4):

If you start CMD with the /C parameter it will terminate when the command is finished.

Answer (score 0):

This would probably work:

```
@ECHO off
CALL environment.bat
cmd.exe /c perlScript1.pl
cmd.exe /c perlScript2.pl
START /MIN perlScript3.pl
cmd.exe /c cleanup.bat
timeout 5
```